# Docker-compose: httpd+php-fpm+mariaDB

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose, lamp

I am trying to make a docker environment LAMP like
But I cant make HTTPD process PHP files

I don't want to use a Linux image

This is how my docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '2'

networks:
    LAMP:

services:
    apache:
        image: httpd:alpine
        container_name: LAMP_apache
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./code:/var/www/html
            - ./httpd/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
        depends_on:
            - php
        networks:
            - LAMP

        # for debugging
        #entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "sleep infinity"]
        # entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 2073600"]

    mariaDB:
        image: mariadb:latest
        container_name: LAMP_mariaDB
        volumes:
            - ./database:/var/lib/mysql:rw
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        depends_on:
            - apache
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=654321          
        networks:
            - LAMP    

    php:
        image: php:fpm-buster
        container_name: LAMP_php
        volumes:
            - ./code:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"       
        networks:
            - LAMP
```

HTTPD is running but shows PHP files code

Can somebody explain what's happening?

Answer (score 3):

I guess your httpd/virtualhost did not contain the information to connect the php-fpm service.
We would need to see your `./httpd/httpd.conf` for example. Or you should check for something like this, somewhere in your httpd configuration :

```
    <FilesMatch \.(php|phar)$>
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php:9000"
    </FilesMatch>
```

Also, for security reason (and convenience), don't export ports 3306 and 9000 on the host if you don't need it.

Hope you've solved your problem though by now :)